# spree install error: "rails g spree:install --user_class=Spree::User" not doing anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have create a new rails app using this command:

```
rails new store
```

rails version is: 4.2.6

Ruby Version:

```
$rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

   ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]

=* ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]`
```

Following is the Gemfile:

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'
 # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
 gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.6'
 # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
 gem 'sqlite3'
 # Use Puma as the app server
 gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
 # Use SCSS for stylesheets
 gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
 # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
 gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
 # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
 gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
 # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
 # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

 # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
 gem 'jquery-rails'
 # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more:                     https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
 gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
 # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
 gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
 # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
 # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
 # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
 # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

 # Use Capistrano for deployment
 # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

 group :development, :test do
   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
   gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
 end

 group :development do
   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
   gem 'web-console'
   gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
   gem 'spring'
   gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
 end

 gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.0'
 gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.1.0'
 gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.1.0'

 # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
 gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Bundle install works fine, But when I try to follow [getting started](https://github.com/spree/spree#getting-started) and run this command

`rails g spree:install --user_class=Spree::User`

Nothing happens at all.

Please let me know what can be wrong?

Here is Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.7.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemerchant (1.49.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.14, < 5.0.0)
      builder (>= 2.1.2, < 4.0.0)
      i18n (>= 0.6.9)
      nokogiri (~> 1.4)
    activemodel (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.7.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.7.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    acts_as_list (0.7.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    addressable (2.4.0)
    arel (6.0.3)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.5.1)
      execjs
    awesome_nested_set (3.0.3)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (9.0.6)
    camertron-eprun (1.1.1)
    cancancan (1.10.1)
    canonical-rails (0.0.11)
      rails (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    carmen (1.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    cldr-plurals-runtime-rb (1.0.1)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.2.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.2.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    colorize (0.8.1)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
    css_parser (1.4.5)
      addressable
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    deface (1.0.2)
      colorize (>= 0.5.8)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      polyglot
      rails (>= 3.1)
    devise (3.5.10)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-encryptable (0.1.2)
      devise (>= 2.1.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    ffaker (2.2.0)
    ffi (1.9.14)
    font-awesome-rails (4.6.3.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
    friendly_id (5.1.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    highline (1.6.21)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jbuilder (2.6.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.2.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    kaminari (0.17.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    listen (3.0.8)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.9.1)
    monetize (1.4.0)
      money (~> 6.7)
    money (6.7.1)
      i18n (>= 0.6.4, <= 0.7.0)
      sixarm_ruby_unaccent (>= 1.1.1, < 2)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.8.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.3.7)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
    paranoia (2.1.5)
      activerecord (~> 4.0)
    polyamorous (1.3.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    premailer (1.8.7)
      css_parser (>= 1.4.5)
      htmlentities (>= 4.0.0)
    premailer-rails (1.9.4)
      actionmailer (>= 3, < 6)
      premailer (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.9)
    puma (3.6.0)
    rabl (0.12.0)
      activesupport (>= 2.3.14)
    rack (1.6.4)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.7.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.7.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.7.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.7.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (11.3.0)
    ransack (1.4.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
    responders (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    select2-rails (3.5.9.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    sixarm_ruby_unaccent (1.1.1)
    spree (3.1.1)
      spree_api (= 3.1.1)
      spree_backend (= 3.1.1)
      spree_cmd (= 3.1.1)
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
      spree_frontend (= 3.1.1)
      spree_sample (= 3.1.1)
    spree_api (3.1.1)
      rabl (~> 0.12.0)
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
      versioncake (~> 2.3.1)
    spree_auth_devise (3.1.0)
      devise (~> 3.5.4)
      devise-encryptable (= 0.1.2)
      spree_core (~> 3.1.0.beta)
    spree_backend (3.1.1)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 3.3)
      jquery-rails (~> 4.1)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      select2-rails (= 3.5.9.1)
      spree_api (= 3.1.1)
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
    spree_cmd (3.1.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    spree_core (3.1.1)
      activemerchant (~> 1.49.0)
      acts_as_list (= 0.7.2)
      awesome_nested_set (~> 3.0.1)
      cancancan (~> 1.10.1)
      carmen (~> 1.0.0)
      deface (~> 1.0.0)
      ffaker (~> 2.2.0)
      font-awesome-rails (~> 4.0)
      friendly_id (~> 5.1.0)
      highline (~> 1.6.18)
      kaminari (~> 0.17)
      monetize (~> 1.1)
      paperclip (~> 4.3.0)
      paranoia (~> 2.1.0)
      premailer-rails
      rails (~> 4.2.7.1)
      ransack (~> 1.4.1)
      responders
      sprockets-rails
      state_machines-activerecord (~> 0.2)
      stringex
      truncate_html (~> 0.9.3)
      twitter_cldr (~> 3.0)
    spree_frontend (3.1.1)
      bootstrap-sass (>= 3.3.5.1, < 3.4)
      canonical-rails (~> 0.0.4)
      jquery-rails (~> 4.1)
      spree_api (= 3.1.1)
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
    spree_gateway (3.1.0)
      spree_core (~> 3.1.0.beta)
    spree_sample (3.1.1)
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
    spring (2.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.12)
    state_machines (0.4.0)
    state_machines-activemodel (0.4.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.1, < 5.1)
      state_machines (>= 0.4.0)
    state_machines-activerecord (0.4.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.1, < 5.1)
      state_machines-activemodel (>= 0.3.0)
    stringex (2.6.1)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    truncate_html (0.9.3)
    turbolinks (5.0.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5)
    turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
    twitter_cldr (3.5.0)
      camertron-eprun
      cldr-plurals-runtime-rb (~> 1.0.0)
      tzinfo
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    versioncake (2.3.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      railties (>= 3.2)
      tzinfo
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (3.3.0)
      activemodel (>= 4.2)
      debug_inspector
      railties (>= 4.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  listen (~> 3.0.5)
  puma (~> 3.0)
  rails (~> 4.2.6)
  sass-rails (~> 5.0)
  spree (~> 3.1.0)
  spree_auth_devise (~> 3.1.0)
  spree_gateway (~> 3.1.0)
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sqlite3
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  web-console

BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.5
```

Comment: you mean nothing relevant shows up on terminal after you execute this ?

Comment: hope you are performing action in correct directory ?

Comment: @Arvind Yes, I am performing in the created app directory, and nothing happens after running this command.

Comment: @sajan yes nothing shows on terminal after executing this.

Comment: what is the spree version installed, check Gemfile.lock

Comment: You should have Required rails version  (~> 4.2.6) for spree 3.1.1

Comment: @Bijendra I have added Gemfile.lock as well, Rails version installed is: 4.2.7.1 and spree is 3.1.1

Comment: same problem, I know this is old, but... just remove spring gem from `gems/spring-2.x.x` and then bundle install again.

Comment: I had to create a rails app with 4.2.6 version of rails, using following command:

`rails _4.2.6_ new store` 
When I was just running rails new store, it used to create dependency using `rails 5` version, which was breaking with spree.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! 
First make sure you have **Devise** initilizer with **secret_key** in it before run above command.

**config/initilizers/devise.rb**

```
Devise.secret_key = "a20fc3f341233168dbc630d965a55792107e1f176784bfb7c6bd4d5762694a533ba273e03365b6614c150f039c42c0e0d"
```

I don't know what the problem exactly was. I hit ctrl+c while waiting and I noticed that

```
gems/spring-2.0.0/lib/spring/client/run.rb:117:in `gets': Interrupt
```

was the brakepoint. I put some debug messages in this file and notice that it opens a socket with (env.socket_name) which was pointing to

```
/run/user/1000/spring-1000/a063a1aa4f0846e81b9eeaf57ad05be4
```

I deleted this file and this fixed the issue. So take a look in your **/run** folder for something about **spring** and remove it, or I think a system reboot will do the job too.