# error in setting up spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have create a new rails app using this command:

```
rails new store
```

rails version is: 4.2.6

Ruby Version:

```
$ rvm rubies
ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.2.2 [ x86_64 ]`
```

When I tried :

```
spree install .
```

I am getting following error:

```
[WARNING] Spree CMD Installer is deprecated. Please follow installation instructions at https://github.com/spree/spree#getting-started
Would you like to install the default gateways? (Recommended) (yes/no) [yes] yes
Would you like to install the default authentication system? (yes/no) [yes] yes
Would you like to run the migrations? (yes/no) [yes] yes
Would you like to load the seed data? (yes/no) [yes] yes
Would you like to load the sample data? (yes/no) [yes] yes
     gemfile  spree
     gemfile  spree_gateway
     gemfile  spree_auth_devise
         run  bundle install from "."
/Users/saurabh.mimani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
    from /Users/saurabh.mimani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/saurabh.mimani/work/codes/spree/store/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I also tried to install as is given in [getting started](https://github.com/spree/spree#getting-started) page, but than I get some other error, which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131331/spree-install-error-rails-g-spreeinstall-user-class-spreeuser-not-doing?noredirect=1#comment67534506_40131331).

Comment: can you try adding spree to the gemfile, running `bundle`, then `bundle exec spree install .`? By the way, it's not good practice on StackOverflow to post multiple questions about the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was:

I had to create a rails app with 4.2.6 version of rails, using following command:

```
rails _4.2.6_ new store
```

When I was just running `rails new store`, it used to create dependency using rails 5 version, which was breaking with spree.

Answer (score 0):

Spree requires [bundler](https://bundler.io) to be installed. Please install it first with

```
gem install bundler
```

That said, with a new Spree project, you should follow the warning of the command line tool and setup your new Spree project the recommended way. This is described on the linked page on https://github.com/spree/spree#getting-started

Comment: `bundler (1.13.5)` is already installed. I tried getting started, but there I stuck with some other error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131331/spree-install-error-rails-g-spreeinstall-user-class-spreeuser-not-doing?noredirect=1#comment67534506_40131331